# Media Creation Tool onto a VHD

Tags: windows-10, vhd, media-creation-tool

I don't have a USB drive (larger than 8GB) handy for the Windows Media Creation Tool (MCT). I am attempting to simulate a USB Flash Drive for MCT using a VHD.

I followed the steps in [this video](https://youtu.be/Ed88lqV6a-o) to create and mount a VHD, but it is not detected in the Media Creation Tool. As noted in a number of the comments on that video, VHDs seem to be totally unrelated to USB Drives for Windows, so the title is misleading.

[image: not detected]

Is there any way to get Media Creation Tool to treat a VHD like a USB Flash Drive so I can install all the files loosely (rather than as an ISO file) into it? Certainly it would be easy enough to simply copy the files out of the ISO onto the drive, but I am wondering if there are any special tricks to make this work automatically. (My reason to do this - if it seems pointless - is I would like to network share the VHD to my HyperV client and test out basic DISM/WSIM management directly on that shared drive.)

Comment: Are you trying to install Windows on a machine not running Windows? You can mount the Windows ISO within Windows and run setup.exe.  You can mount the Windows image contained within an ISO file easily enough

Comment: @Ramhound no, I am trying to experiment with image management ecosystem on Windows, so i need access to the `sources\install.wim` file (e.g, create answer files, catalog files, etc)

Comment: That can be done with DISM without the ISO being written to a flash drive.  All you have to do is mount the ISO within Windows.

Comment: @Ramhound indeed! i am wondering if I can work with VHDs directly somehow, without using an ISO file

Comment: Media Creation Tool likely won't let you write to a non-removable drive, however, Rufus would let you do that with some warnings.

Comment: Can you clarify;
-are you trying to simulate USB like "live" boot on VHDx(this is pretty simple)?
You can also install OS on VHX and if you dont use EFI boot, you can use VHD(x) for multi(or dual) boot options.

-Or you just want to open install.wim locally and edit it, witch is a bit more messy, but as mentioned you will need to use dism, but before DISM "Mount-WindowsImage -ImagePath C:\PathTo\ExtractedISO\sources\install.wim -Index 6 -Path C:\PathTo\MountOffline", index depends on ISO pack.

Comment: @Danijel i am wanting the latter - looking to play with the local `.wim` file with DISM. could you expand on the ISO pack index? i am having trouble finding references to it online

Comment: Look for (Get-WindowsImage -ImagePath X:\path\to\install.wim), you can also manipulate them and delete ones you dont want with (Remove-WindowsImage -ImagePath "X:\path\to\install.wim" -Index 11), or use (Mount-WindowsImage -ImagePath X:\path\to\install.wim -Index 6 -Path C:\Mount\Offline)